# Aws Cognito Presignup trigger fails with InvalidLambdaResponseException

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

My pre-signup-trigger lambda fails with the InvalidLambdaResponseException. Using nodejs. The user registration works without the trigger.

I tried pretty much all solutions suggested on SO how to handle this trigger. I have tried ending the lambda with context.done(null, event) and callback(null, event). The test script works.
Worth mentioning that I have around 10 user attributes including 7 custom.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

// Check if business phone exists
event.response.autoConfirmEmail = false;
// This example uses a custom attribute "custom:domain"
if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("custom:business_phone")) {
    if ( event.request.userAttributes["custom:business_phone"] !== null
    && event.request.userAttributes["custom:business_phone"] !== "") {
        event.response.autoConfirmEmail = true;
    }
}

// Return to Amazon Cognito
callback(null, event);

//context.done(null, event);    
};
```

Test event works but user signup in browser returns InvalidLambdaResponseException. Tried one or both of the last two lines.

**UPDATE:** Getting same exception for Post confirm trigger. used aws doc example as is. Using runtime NodeJs 10.x. Tried 8.10 too.

To all he experts out there, please help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out the error was caused by *another* lambda that I had in my cloudformation:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  if (event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_ForgotPassword") {
    event.response.emailSubject = "Reset your password for blah";
    event.response.emailMessage = "Blah blah";
    callback(null, event);
  }
};
```

As signup sends an email, it was also executing the above lambda. But `callback(null, event);` was inside `if` statement and therefore not executed, since `event.triggerSource` was not `"CustomMessage_ForgotPassword"`.

Fixing that by putting `callback(null, event);` outside of `if` statement solved the whole problem.

I'd suggest checking your other lambdas if they always execute `callback(null, event)` in the end, because error may be caused by a different lambda than you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to use **async** at the handler function definition. Looks like you did too.

Link to current developer guide, where an updated example is provided showing the use of an async function that only returns the  handler event instead of  calling callback or context:

```
const handler = async (event) => {
  // Confirm the user
  event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
  // Set the email as verified if it is in the request
  if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
    event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
  }

  // Set the phone number as verified if it is in the request
  if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("phone_number")) {
    event.response.autoVerifyPhone = true;
  }

  return event;
};

export { handler };
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-registration-example-2